# UWP: How can I resize uwp app window at runtime as I do it with my mouse?

Tags: uwp, resize, window

I need to resize my app window as we usually do it by dragging mouse at a border of the window. How can I do this programatically in runtime?

Comment: I dont have a source for this but as far as I know UWP is a shell and one should not be able to modify outside resources. The window of your application is such an outside resource. I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for an explanation

Answer (score 2):

The closest API to doing this in UWP is this one:

**ApplicationView.TryResizeView(Size) Method**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview